# UI Tests with Jenkins and CasperJS

Tags: testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, casperjs

I have a script that checks whether all application modules are up and returning the result correctly, but need to test the **upload .xlsx and .zip files**. 
I'm developing in `CasperJS` and desire to integrate with `Jenkins` (which I'm still learning about).
 My question is: How do I access these .xlsx files and zip when integrating with Jenkins?
 Just put in the Jenkins workspace directory and access or is something more complex than having to use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)? There's another solution? (may be one that doesn't use Jenkins and CasperJS)

Comment: So to be clear: You have tests written in CasperJS that perform tests that use `zip` and `xlsx` files. You have a Jenkins job that runs the tests, but you're not sure where to put the `xlsx`/`zip` source files?

Comment: @Bto exactly. Jenkins isn't running the tests now but I want do this.

Answer (score 2):

The parameterized trigger won't do what you need; its purpose is to pass parameters/variables from a job to the jobs it is triggering.

You are on the right track with putting the files in the workspace, but you need a good way of getting them there: You should store the xlsx and zip files on a server accessible to the build slave and retrieve them on-demand before the CasperJS tests run.

The [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) might be what you're after. From their description:

> This plugin allows to copy a set of files, from a location somewhere on the master node, to jobs' workspaces.

To use it, you would copy your xlsx/zip files onto the Jenkins master, say:

```
$JENKINS_HOME/userContent/casperjs/testZip.zip
$JENKINS_HOME/userContent/casperjs/testXL.xlsx
```

In the build job, you would check the box for **Copy files into the job's workspace before building** and, for files to copy, you would put `casperjs/**`. Your CasperJS tests could then refer to them as `casperjs/testZip.zip` and `casperjs/testXL.xlsx`.

You could use other techniques (`scp` and `curl` come to mind), but the Copy to Slave is probably the most "Jenkinsy" way of doing it.